# jquery chosen: how to onClick for a special option

Tags: jquery, onclick, html-select, jquery-chosen

I'm using jquery chosen to create a multiple select box.
My problem is, that the third option must to open a new window and must not select.
(later the user can create a new option in this window)

can someone help me to realize this?
My idea is to use `$('.chosen-select').on('change'...)` for this and remove the selected item from the list.
But I don't know how

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <select data-placeholder="options" style="width:350px;" multiple class="chosen-select">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3" onClick="openPopup()">3</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it:

```
 $('.chosen-select').chosen().change( function() {
      var selectedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
      if(selectedValue=='3'){
        $(this).find('option:selected').prop("selected",false);
        openPopup();
      }
      $('.chosen-select').trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood it right this should solve your problem:

```
$('.chosen-select').on('mouseup', function(){ // on finish the click on any part of the multiselect
   if($(this).val().indexOf('3') !== -1){ // if value has the 3 selected [1,3]
      openPopup(); // open the popup
   }
});
```

But if you want it to work only on the option 3 you can do this

```
$('.chosen-select').on('mouseup','.openPopup', function(){ // on finish the click on option of class openPopup
   if($(this).val() == 3){
      openPopup(); // open the popup
   }
});
```

As for the removal:

```
$('.chosen-select').on('mouseup','.openPopup', function(){ // on finish the click on option of class openPopup
   if($(this).val() == 3){
      openPopup($(this)); // open the popup
   }
});

function openPopup(obj){
    //Popup functions...
    obj.remove();
}
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: thanks, but than the object is selected too, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$('option[value="3"]').click(function(e){

    // The line below is just for demonstration purposes
    // you could replace with your openPopup() function

    window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');

    // Remove the element
    $(this).remove();

    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Here is a fiddle that shows the behavior in action: http://jsfiddle.net/95xS5/2/